# How to save current cmd-output

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, command-prompt

Is there a way to get whats currently displayed on the windows command prompt?

For example:

```
print('some text')
print('some different text')

>>> some text
>>> some different text

a = save_whats_on_cmd()
>>> a = 'some text \n some different text'
```

Comment: Where do you want to save it?

Comment: @DevangSanghani in a `.txt`-file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rick_2650 here is an improved version of the function as you wanted

```
# log function prints message and
# saves the output in log.txt of
# the current working directory
# sample usage [green text ANSI 1;32]:-
#     >>> log("hello", "world", colour="1;32")
#
# @param   objects  *args    objects we want to print
# @param   string   colour   ANSI style colour codes 
# @param   string   sep      Separator for __str__ of objects    
# @param   string   end      String to be added at lineend
# @param   string   logfile  name of logfile
# @return  void
def log(*args, sep=" ", colour="0", end="\n", logfile="log.txt"):

    printable_array = []
    colour = "\033[" + colour + "m"

    with open(logfile, "a") as file:
        for each in args:
            printable_array.append(colour+each+"\033[0m")
            file.write(each+sep) # seperator will effect the final entry
        file.write(end)

    print(*printable_array, sep=sep, end=end, flush=True)
```

Comment: That's amazing :)
I didn't know that it's possible to 'pre-set' arguments like that. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest wrap the print with your own function

```
>>> output_file_name = "output.txt"

>>> def cmd_print(*args, **kwargs):
...     with open(output_file_name, "a") as file:
...         for each in args:
...             print(each.__str__())
...             file.write(each.__str__()+"\r\n")
...             # \r\n linebreaks are dos only use \n for *nix
...
>>> cmd_print("you can do strings", ["lists", "too"])
```

The answer assumes that you have control over the code
which means you can choose to replace print commands

if its not the case the quick and dirty way is to overwrite print

```
>>> output_file_name = "output.txt"
>>> pythonic_print = print
>>> def print(*args, **kwargs):
...     with open(output_file_name, "a") as file:
...         for each in args:
...             pythonic_print(each.__str__())
...             file.write(each.__str__()+"\r\n")
...             # \r\n linebreaks are dos only use \n for *nix
...
>>> print("you can do strings", ["lists", "too"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a file, let say `mylib.py`

```
import sys


class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.terminal = sys.stdout
        self.log = open('log.dat', 'w')

    def write(self, message):
        self.terminal.write(message)
        self.log.write(message)

    def flush(self):
        pass
```

Then open your interpreter:

```
>>> from mylib import Logger
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout = Logger()
>>> print(1)
1
>>> print(2)
2
>>> print(3)
3
>>> exit()
```

See log.dat:

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

I used @omar's solution to my problem and modified it for it to fit perfectly for my needs. Here is what I wrote:

```
def log(text, **kwargs): # possible arguments: colour, end
    logfile = open('log.txt', 'a')
    if kwargs == {}: 
        # normal print statement: no colour, no end=''
        print(text)
        logfile.write(text + '\n')
    else:
        if 'colour' in kwargs and 'end' in kwargs: 
            # both colour and end=''
            print(f'\x1b[{kwargs["colour"]}m{text}\x1b[0m', end='', flush=True)
            logfile.write(text)
        elif 'colour' in kwargs:
            # only colour
            print(f'\x1b[{kwargs["colour"]}m{text}\x1b[0m')
            logfile.write(text + '\n')
        elif 'end' in kwargs: 
            # only end=''
            print(text, end='', flush=True)
            logfile.write(text)
    logfile.close()
```

I didn't want sth like `\x1b[1;31;42mSOMETEXT\x1b[0m` to appear in the log so I made the colour-stuff be an argument. Result in the log-file is then only `SOMETEXT`.

For the `end` argument it's irrelevant what's assigned to it. I just needs to be mentioned.

This makes the log-file like a second command prompt - only colourless.

**If anyone has any ideas about how to improve my function, please tell me because I think it looks quite messy.**  **:P**

Thanks for the anwsers :)